# Regex to match X repeated exactly n times in a row

Tags: regex

I am attempting to use regex to match a pattern where we have some X (any character) which occurs exactly n many times in succession. I know a little about regex, but don't know of anything like this.

My previous attempts left me using (.) as a capture group for my X, but I wasn't able to find a way to make sure this happened *exactly* n times (no more, and no less)

(Edit) For more context, I am trying to separate strings (containing only the letters 'r', 'p', and 's') into either "human" or "machine" generated and I want to assume that any string which has "XrrrrX" (where X is either s or p) or "YssssY" (where Y is either r or p) or "ZppppZ" (where Z is either s or r).

Some sample examples are

```
psrsrprrsssrrrpsprprsppspsssrsrssrpprppsrpssrp
psrpsprpsrpprpsprpsprpsrpprppsrpsprsprsprppsrp
psrrrrsprsrpsrrsprrrrrprpssssrsprrpspspppprpsr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

where I want to match only strings that have at most 5 of any character in a row and also at least one occurrence of xxxxx (where x is any character repeated 5 times in a row)

Comment: You need a backreference I think. Something along the lines of `^(.)\1{4}$` to match 5 times 'X' for example. Note that it's important to use anchors or any other way to define the start/end of your match.

Comment: The above regex returned "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" as containing a match, but I wouldn't want this to match as there are more than 5 repeated characters

Comment: are you [sure](https://regex101.com/r/cNkFY2/1)?

Comment: Oh my, I forgot the $. It works, but I also want the regex to match a string such as asdfarrrrrasdf since it contains a character repeated 5 times, but I don't care about the rest so long as a character is only repeated at most 5 times

Comment: In such case you should include these examples in your question above. Write down what to match, what not to match. For example, what if you have a string that contains a character matched exactly 5 times but another character is matched 6 times?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated my question to try and be more clear

Comment: I don't understand the paragraph you added beginning "(Edit)". You say you want to separate strings into "human" or "machine" generated, but you don't define those terms. If those terms are not relevant get rid of them. You then say you want to assume that strings with property A, B or C.  Assume what? It is as though the end of that sentence is missing. The main problem, however, is that you fail to show how the four example strings you give are to be "separated". When you give an example in an SO question please always show the desired result, even when it is obvious to you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a back-reference to your capture group. Here is an example regex:

```
(.)\1{2}
```

Regex explained:

- `(.)` is a capture group that captures literally anything a single time
- `\1` is a back-reference to the group you just captured (that single character)
- `{2}` is a quantifier, which matches the previous token (the `\1`) exactly twice.

Note that, to capture a single character n times, you have to specify `{n - 1}` as the quantifier because the first match was already captured by `(.)`.

Comment: The issue is that when I do this, "rrrr" is captured even if the string is "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr", but I want it to capture the group ONLY if it appears exactly n times and no more

Comment: This currently captures *exactly* three characters ([here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3NjEZ/1)). Do you mean it gives more than one capture?

Comment: I want to either capture a group of the given string has exactly n occurrences of any given character and not capture it otherwise

Comment: Can you give examples of input and expected output? It helps clear my doubts.

Comment: I have updated my question to try and be more clear in what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should do what you'r after:

```
^(?!([psr]*?([psr])\2{4})\2)(?1)(?2)*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GGalcG/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!` - Open a negative lookahead;

  - `([psr]*?([psr])\2{4})\2)` - A nested 1st capture group to match 0+ (Lazy) characters of `[psr]` upto another nested 2nd capture group of any of those characters. Right after is a backreference to the 2nd capture group which we match 4 times. After that we match the content of the 2nd capture group once more to avoid it occur 6+ times before we close the negative lookahead;
- `(?1)` - Match the same subpattern as the 1st group;
- `(?2)*` - Match the same subpattern as the 2nd group 0+ (Greedy) times upto;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

---

I suppose this would be short for something like:

```
^(?![psr]*?([psr])\1{5})[psr]*?([psr])\2{4}[psr]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you wish to match any of the following strings:

```
'psssssp'
'sppppps'
'rsssssr'
'srrrrrs'
'prrrrrp'
'rpppppr'
```

(but I have a [sneaking suspicion](https://www.yourdictionary.com/sneaking-suspicion) that you actually want to do something else, in which case please tell me in a comment).

That could be done by matching a simple alternation:

```
(?:psssssp|sppppps|rsssssr|srrrrrs|prrrrrp|rpppppr)
```

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression that employs back-references:

```
([psr])(?!\1)([psr])\2{4}\1
```

​[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFHUse/1)

The second regular expression has the following components.

```
([psr])  # match 'p', 's' or 'r' and save to capture group 1
(?!\1)   # the next character cannot be the content of capture group 1
([psr])  # match 'p', 's' or 'r' and save to capture group 2
\2{4}    # match the content of capture group 2 four times
\1       # match the content of capture group 1
```

`(?!\1)` is a *negative lookahead*.